# How to prevent app from crashing in case JSON answer is empty?

Tags: json, swift

I have a API call which sometimes returns empty because there are no data in the DB. In such a case, the app crashes with the following error message.

> Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x108156ae8)   to 'NSArray' (0x108156b88).

How can I prevent the app from crashing in case the JSON object is empty?

This is the class:

```
restApi.getAllNonAcademicSchools(self.shareData.token_type, accessToken: self.shareData.access_token, countryISOcode: self.shareData.studyLocationISOcode) {responseObject, error in
        // use responseObject and error here

        //create custom session with auth header / token from REST API for getting images
        let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

        //Get the access token here and create HTTP header used for auth
        let xHTTPAdditionalHeaders: [String : String] = ["Authorization" : self.shareData.token_type + " " + self.shareData.access_token]

        sessionConfig.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = xHTTPAdditionalHeaders
         self.imageDownloader = ImageDownloader(
            configuration: sessionConfig,
            downloadPrioritization: .LIFO,
            maximumActiveDownloads: 4,
            imageCache: AutoPurgingImageCache()
        )
        print("imageDownloader object created")
        print("print the json data from api ")
        self.items = NSDictionary(dictionary: responseObject! as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        //access the inner array from the json answer called result

            self.resultList = self.items["result"] as! [[String:
                AnyObject]] //This is the line which causes the error
            print(self.resultList)


            self.tableView!.reloadData() // reload tableview when result comes back from async call

    }
```

If data is available in the DB, everything works fine.

If data is in the DB, the following JSON response is being returned and everything works fine:

```
(
    {
    address = "Modern Mansion, Xiangyang South Rd, Bldg. A, 9th Floor, Room 910, Shanghai";
    city = Shanghai;
    "cou_id" = CN;
    environment = L;
    image = "LTL_Mandarin_Shanghai_3.jpeg";
    name = "LTL Mandarin School";
    rating = 0;
    "sco_id" = 26;
    "sco_type" = LS;
    },
    ...
)
```

Comment: I guess you have to check if responseObject is nil first, else forcing unwrapping ("responseObject!") will crash

Comment: Try using the concept of optional chaining. This concept introduced in the swift used to check whether response is nil or nor. Refer to the link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `if let` or `guard` for `Optional wrapping` instead of `force wrapping` for that.

**Using if let**

```
if let response = self.items["result"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
    self.resultList = response
}
```

**Using guard**

```
guard let response = self.items["result"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {
     return
}
self.resultList = response
```

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy Coding:)

Comment: One suggestion you are calling `reloadData` twice, you need to call this method only once inside this function after you get array response check that too.

Comment: Thx! I changed that now. Thanks a lot